# Error while running D3.JS v4 on Angular2

Tags: angular, d3.js

I've got this issue when transpiling my app:

```
(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/d3-ng2-service wrapF…
```

I installed d3.js following the link https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-ng2-service as follows:

```
pm install d3-ng2-service --save
```

And followed all instructions contained in the link.

What am I missing?

(I use: npm 4.1.1 and node 6.9.4)

[UPDATED]
My systemjs.config.js is now as follows:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'd3-ng2-service':            'npm:d3-ng2-service',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'd3-ng2-service': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

With this updated config file, I now have the following error:

```
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
    wrapFn@http://loc…
```

My folders:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from a line similar to the following:

```ts
import { D3Service } from 'd3-ng2-service';
```

For SystemJS to be able to resolve this import, you need to teach it where to locate the `d3-ng2-service` library.

If you're using the official Angular Quickstart, there is a [systemjs.config.js](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/systemjs.config.js) that contains code that can help you. Try to locate the `map` for `rxjs` in this file and use that as an example.

You should end up with an additional `map` in your config that looks something like this:

```js
map : {
  'd3-ng2-service': 'npm:d3-ng2-service',
  // ...
}
```

You might also need to define the entry point for the package:

```js
packages: {
  'd3-ng2-service': {
    main: './index.js'
  }
}
```

You can alter the original `systemjs.config.js` but the quickstart also provides a [systemjs.config.extras.js](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/systemjs.config.extras.js) specifically to store your customizations.

Comment: By adding 'd3-ng2-service': 'npm:d3-ng2-service' in the map section of my systems.config.js I still have the issue: which is bizarre because I see the d3-ng2-service in the node_modules folder (see updated question) @AngularFrance

Comment: same thing with this (see the current config file in my question) @AngularFrance,  the traceur error is there. I wonder why it try to fetch the file at the root rather than the /node_modules folder…

Comment: Did you manage to get it working after all? I have the same problem, also using the official angular quickstart and d3-ng2-service. Posted my own question here, but no luck so far https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490789/importing-d3-js-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
'd3-ng2-service':            'npm:d3-ng2-service',
```

in your system.js config doesn't look right.  It needs to point to the path of the JS module.

Looking at your node_modules screenshot, try:

```
'd3-ng2-service':  'npm:d3-ng2-service/esm/index.js',
```

Comment: Now I have an issue with /traceur at line d3Service in my component as follows:  constructor(
  private element: ElementRef, 
  private d3Service: D3Service,

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca, try `'d3-ng2-service': 'npm:d3-ng2-service/index.js'` as the path instead.

Comment: Same thing (I had first tried this). But I noticed (by comparing against what I had before installing D3) that I have now more file in nodes_mobules, including 'traceur'. How it comes? Shouldn't have to alter some config files?

Comment: Try adding the path to `index.js` under the `packages` key, NOT under the `app` key. See my updated answer.