# Importing D3.js in Angular 4

Tags: angular, d3.js

I've just moved from php to Angular 2, without much javascript or typescript experience. Therefore I need your help filling in a gap.

I'm working on a rather large app, where I need to use D3.js. My development app is build on top of the official quickstart (https://github.com/angular/quickstart).

I'm trying to import d3-ng2-service (https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-ng2-service) and as far as I read on SO and github the code is correct. However it doesn't work. Here's some code bellow, edited for brevity.

src/app/app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { D3Service } from 'd3-ng2-service';

*...*

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    *...*
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    *...*
  ],
  providers: [  
    D3Service,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ 
    *...*
  ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

src/systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
      'app': 'app',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',

      'ng2-file-upload' : 'npm:ng2-file-upload',
      'd3-ng2-service' : 'npm:d3-ng2-service', 
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      /** Configuration for ng2-file-upload */
      'ng2-file-upload' : { 
        main: './ng2-file-upload.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'd3-ng2-service' : { 
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
    }
  });
})(this);
```

The error I'm getting in console is  this:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/traceur 404 (Not Found)
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1075:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:498:34)
        at invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1370:14)
        at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1388:17)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
    Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:3000/node_modules/d3-ng2-service/index.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/d3-ng2-service/index.js as "d3-ng2-service" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1075:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:498:34)
        at invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1370:14)
        at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1388:17)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
    Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:3000/node_modules/d3-ng2-service/index.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/d3-ng2-service/index.js as "d3-ng2-service" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
```

I can confirm that all paths are correct.
In node_modules/d3-ng2-service/index.js there is a single statement:

```
export * from './src/d3.service';
```

Do I need some additional dependencies to read this statement? 
I am not using webpack and d3-ng2-service does not prove an .umd entry point.

Comment: Possibly change the systemjs.config.js to point to the umd.js file instead of the index.js. - per this issue  - Googled on traceur not found
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11358#issuecomment-244906719    so I think you have to do that for d3-ng2-service - I'd guess.

Comment: I'd also see if you can see any plunkers for d3-ng2-service - they would likely have systemjs.config.js setup correctly and you could compare yours to that.

Comment: This looks a bit hairy.. But possibly you can create a umd via webpack. http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/javascript-library-starter-using-webpack-es6 - Not sure if that's a rabbit hole you want to go down..

Comment: @JGFMK thank you for answers. Yes, the problem is that d3-ng2-service does not provide an .umd file (also updated this in the question).

Looking at plunkers is a good idea, I'll try that. I already used this demo to try out some d3 functionality https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-ng2-demo  but I don't see any configuration which would answer my question here. 

Also tried adding webpack to my project but for some reason I didn't manage.

Comment: can you please tell us why you are not using angular-cli?

Comment: @Benas, you may be right, that should solve the issue. I'll move my project to CLI and come back with an update.

Comment: @ValiMunteanu Was it d3-ng2-service/index.js or d3-ng2-service/index.ts? https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-ng2-service/blob/master/index.ts

Comment: There's a decent video on Youtube discussing various module loading methods, and build tools here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4ja6HeBm6s by Curran Kelleher

Comment: Thank you for you help guys, I switched to Angular CLI (which was the sensible thing to do anyway) and d3 is imported without any problem, no additional configuration needed.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't use `d3-ng2-service`.  I am on Angular 9 at the moment.

I import it like so:

```
npm install d3 --save-dev
```

Then, in my TypeScript file, I import it like:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

Then, I use it like so:

```
private svg;
...
this.svg = d3.select('figure#chart')
```

And my HTML element looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <figure id="chart"></figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am a total beginner at Angular.  So, I can't believe I have to be the person answering your question.

Comment: To get this working I also had to install d3's `@types` to resolve a TypeScript error. `npm install --save-dev @types/d3`